# Program ends once reaching for()loop with no error messages

Tags: c++

I'm creating a "company" profile creator for fun and have set up a for() loop that should run until its printed every company profile created in the session. Instead. the program either displays an empty list or ends abruptly once you've finished inputting all of the user profiles. I've tried rewriting the for loop with different symbols to no avail, and don't like going to c++ help sites until I'm completely out of ideas on what's causing the program to fail, any help greatly appreciated
(Ignore the comments, I'm gonna show this to my friends who don't know c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
float height[100] = {};//Arrays for the Heights that will be recorded into the program
    int age[100] = {};//Arrays for the Ages that will be recorded into the program
    string name[100] = {};//Arrays for the names that will be recorded into the program
    double sumHeight;//Used to calculate the average Height in the "Fun Stats" Section
    int sumAge;//Used to calculate the average Age in the "Fun Stats" Section
    int count;
    int count2;

                                                  

    cout << "Welcome to the CZAR company profile creator, enter the info of 5 employees at a time to register them into our database and register them for company cards and other benefits.\n\n\n";
    cin >> count;
    count = count-1;
        for (int a=0; a <= count; a++ ){//Loop that allows the information to be recorded without rewriting the code several times. Saves processing power and very good.
            cout << "PROFILE " << a+1 << ":\n";
            cout << "What's their first name?\n";
            cin >> name[a];//Lets the array number increase by one every time the for loop restarts
            cout << "How old are they?\n";
            cin >> age[a];
            cout << "How tall are they?\n";
            cin >> height[a];
        }
  //This is where the program stops
    cout << "Profiles generated:\n"; 
      for (int b = 0; b >= count; b++){
      int c = b - 1;
    cout << "Profile " << b <<")" << name[c] << ", " << age[c] <<", ";
    cout  << fixed << setprecision(2) << height[c] << "\n";
  }//Stops the height variable from displaying more than 2 decimals when outputted

    cout << "\n\n\n Fun stats:\n";
    
    
    
    sumHeight = height[0]+height[1]+height[2]+height[3]+height[4];
    sumAge = age[0]+age[1]+age[2]+age[3]+age[4];
    
    
    cout << "Average Height of all profiles:";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << sumHeight / count << "\n";//Calculates the average Height. setprecision and fixed are there to limit the output from being unnecesarily long
    cout << "Average Age of all profiles:" << sumAge / count << "\n";//Calculates the average Age
    cout << "\n\n\n Profiles succesfully generated.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo, most likely. The Boolean expression is immediately false. Your operator is likely flipped.

Comment: I would also recommend a program like clang-format to style your code for you, and to get rid of useless comments.

Comment: use std::vector instead of fixed size arrays

Comment: I recommend using an array of `struct` rather than parallel arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop here is using `>=` condition not `<=` so it exits immediately without executing the code inside the brackets.

```
for (int b = 0; b <= count; b++)
{
    int c = b - 1;
    cout << "Profile " << b <<")" << name[c] << ", " << age[c] <<", ";
    cout  << fixed << setprecision(2) << height[c] << "\n";
}
```

Also remember that you need to initialize any variables you use and that c++ arrays are 0-based not (-1)-based.

Comment: They (oddly) decrement `count` so that they can use `<=`. It's a poor practice to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm facing the problem of the program not outputting the final profile. For example, if I input 3 profiles Profile 1)Matt, 31, 175.32, Profile 2)Stephen, 29, 192.54, Profile 3) Jessica, 24, 163.85... I'd only get Matt and Stephen's profile in the final output. How can I fix this?

Comment: @frogovalgoggles Whenever you have a loop that doesn't execute on the last element it is most certainly going to be an indexing problem. Try playing around with the limits on your loop and incrementor